# Find if two dates are more than 6 months apart with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

so for my university coursework, i have to create an oracle database for an airline. (this is my first time working with oracle)

part of my requirement is to identify whether pilots are fit to fly. to do this, my employee and pilot_test tables are set up as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE PILOT_TEST (
  TEST_ID NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  TEST_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
  POSITION VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL, /* pilot, booking clerk, maintenance staff*/
  EMPLOYED_FROM DATE NOT NULL,
  EMPLOYED_TO DATE NOT NULL,
  TELEPHONE NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NULL,
  ADDRESS_LINE1 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS_LINE2 VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
  TOWN VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  POST_CODE VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
  SALARY NUMBER(6,2) NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL /*working, on leave, contract expired, fired*/
);
```

whenever a new flight is added to the system, i use a trigger to check whether the staff allocated to fly the plane is actually a pilot. 
into this trigger i would like to check that if he IS a pilot, then whether his last TEST_DATE is less than 6 months old or not. any ideas on how this could be done?

my current trigger looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_PILOT_ALLOCATION
BEFORE INSERT ON FLIGHT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    TEMP_POSITION VARCHAR2(13);
BEGIN

SELECT POSITION INTO TEMP_POSITION 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = :NEW.PILOT_ID;

IF UPPER (TEMP_POSITION) <> 'PILOT' THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Assigned employee is not a pilot');

ELSIF   
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DECLARE 
    TEMP_POSITION VARCHAR2(13);
    TEMP_TESTDATE DATE;
BEGIN

SELECT E.POSITION, 
       (SELECT MAX (TEST_DATE) 
          FROM PILOT_TEST PT 
         WHERE PT.TEST_DATE <= SYSDATE 
           AND PT.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID) TEST_DATE 
  INTO TEMP_POSITION, 
       TEMP_TESTDATE 
  FROM EMPLOYEE E
 WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = :NEW.PILOT_ID;

IF UPPER (TEMP_POSITION) <> 'PILOT' 
THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Assigned employee is not a pilot');
END IF;

IF ( SYSDATE - TEMP_TESTDATE ) > 182 
THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Assigned pilot has not been tested in the last 6 months');
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: The educational part here: Oracle allows you to do day-based data arithmetic by adding and subtracting whole numbers from dates, and returns days when you subtract a date from another date.

Answer (score 2):

I would just outer join the two tables together and check if they're a pilot. Checking the cert date can be done with a case statement. Note the existence of the built-in ADD_MONTHS function to do the date arithmetic for you. I like to do as much as I can within the select statement. Finally, I would check for the existence of the employee as well with the exception handler. Generally speaking, you should always have exception handlers for your SQL. I've seen too many cases where someone assumed that since a record *should* be there they didn't handle the exception, and of course it eventually did happen. At that point you get Oracle generating the exception in an ungraceful way.

```
BEGIN

  SELECT e.employee_id, NVL(UPPER(e.position),'xx')
       , CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS(MAX(test_date), 6) > SYSDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END date_ck
    INTO v_id, v_pos, v_date_ck
    FROM employee e LEFT JOIN pilot_test p ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
   WHERE e.employee_id = :new.pilot_id
   GROUP BY e.employee_id, NVL(UPPER(e.position),'xx');

  IF v_pos <> 'PILOT' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Not a pilot');
  ELSIF v_date_ck = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'Not recently tested');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003, 'Not an employee');
END;
```